# Php header redirecting for file force download not working

Tags: php

I am having an issue of header redirecting and force download on files having size greater than 1GB.

this code works fine for files having size less than approx 1GB

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '18364M');

header('Content-Type: application/bin');

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.bin"');

readfile('Setup.bin');'
```

Comment: Please be more specific with the output that you are seeing and what your question is exactly

Comment: Have you any error output in that case ?

Comment: no error output was shown....just the file downloaded (having size more than 1gb ) was almost empty in size....just say i want to download file of 1.2gb...but it will be downloaded as 2kb.........Sorry but i can't describe it properly.....you have to try the code to know the problem occuring

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that ? *[PHP Script to force download big files using chunk](http://PHP%20Script%20to%20force%20download%20big%20files%20using%20chunk)*

**Source code:**

```
<?php
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/Setup.bin";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (FALSE !== ($handler = fopen($file, 'r'))) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); //changed to chunked
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');

        //Send the content in chunks
        while (false !== ($chunk = fread($handler, 4096))) {
            echo $chunk;
        }
    }
    exit;
}
echo "<h1>Content error</h1><p>The file does not exist!</p>";?>
?>
```